# ConvertTo-HTML variable

Tags: html, powershell, variables

I have a PowerShell script that pulls a logfiles from multiple folders and outputs the data as an HTML file. I need to insert the folder name into the HTML file from a PowerShell variable any idea on how to convert a PowerShell `$variable` into a usable HTML format for my report? Below is my script:

```cs
$a = Get-Date -Format M.d
$Test = (Get-Content -Path "\\Test\d$\APSO\LCI\Scripts\MW\AllServers.txt")
foreach ($Server in $Test) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "\\test\LogFiles\BackupEventLogs\$Server\" -Exclude *.evt* |
        ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} |
        ConvertTo-Html -Property LastWriteTime, Name >> \\test\d$\APSO\LCI\Checks\Backups$a.html
}
```

Comment: Insert what? Where? What doesn't work the way you expected? What *are* you expecting anyway? Also, when posting code please make sure it's a [mcve] and not introducing other errors your original code doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an additional variable that holds the results from the file info.
Something like...

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Temp\diff\TestFile_4.txt).DirectoryName
(Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Temp\diff\TestFile_4.txt).Directory.Name

D:\Temp\diff
diff
```

Then pass the variable as you normally would.